# Who is the culprit?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

"  Andy says: "Cindy is guilty".

Bart says: "I am not guilty".

Cindy says: "Danny is guilty".

Danny says: "Cindy lies if she says I am guilty".

We know there is exactly one guilty person and exactly one person who says the truth. Who is guilty?"

I am getting confused on how to write this symbolically. Is this correct? Then how do I verify who is guilty?

$$Andy_{truth} \implies Cindy_{Guilty} \\ 
Bart_{truth} \implies \lnot Bart_{Guilty} \\
Cindy_{truth} \implies Danny_{Guilty} \\
Danny_{truth} \implies \lnot Cindy_{truth}$$

Comment: Notation looks a bit odd to me, but statements are correct. As to how to solve the puzzle - if Bart says the truth, then everyone else lies.

Comment: What do you mean by odd?

Comment: Yeah, the Bart guy sounds suspicious.

Comment: @Gloomy That I don't usually see such notation. I would write something like $S_{Andy} = Guilty(Cindy)$, seeing how "Guilty" is a predicate. Also, statement of Danny "as is" is a bit tricky - it's $(S_{Cindy} \implies Guilty(Danny)) \implies \neg S_{Cindy}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any of Andy or Cindy says truth this mean Bart is not guilty which implies Bart also says truth (because if Bart lies then he is not guilty will be a false statement this mean he is guilty which is not our case) , thus we have two persons who says truth, which is not our case.

Therefore ANDY AND CINDY ARE BOTH MAKING FALSE STATEMENTS. THUS CINDY AND DANNY ARE NOT GUILTY.

now if Bart is speaking truth this means Danny is making false statement(because only one person speaks trurth), this mean Cindy was speaking truth which will again a contradiction.

THEREFORE DANNY IS SPEAKING TRUTH AND BART IS GUILTY.

Comment: Why does bart not guilty imply that bart says the truth? (I understand intuitively but logically, $$ (a \implies b) \neq ( b\implies a )$$, therefore $$\lnot Bart_{Guilty} \implies Bart_{truth}$$ shouldn't be correct?

Comment: This is double implicative statement, Bart says truth iff he is not guilty.

Comment: Thank you, but how do you deduce it's a $ \iff $ from the text? The other ones are only normal $\implies$ right?

Comment: Bart says truth implys he is not guilty, I think this much is clear to you.

Comment: Now i need to show if Bart is not guilty then he is speaking truth. If possible suppose he lies i.e. he is guilty which will be contradiction to our assumption that Bart is not guilty.

Comment: But then actually these are all iff statements?

Comment: I have done some editing in answer in parenthesis, lookout that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the correct notation would be

$$Andy_{truth} \iff Cindy_{Guilty} \\ 
Bart_{truth} \iff \lnot Bart_{Guilty} \\
Cindy_{truth} \iff Danny_{Guilty} \\
Danny_{truth} \iff \lnot Cindy_{truth}$$ 
Because if any right-hand side statement is true than the corresponding left-hand side is also true.

This with Anurag Jain's answer solves the question. Thank you :-)